# What's the server-side equivalent of $.ajax() in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, authorization

I want to perform an HTTP request from server-side code in a Google App Script with an `Authorization` header. Is there an App Script API for sending HTTP requests?

What's the equivalent of this code in a Google Apps Script?

```
 var api = "URL";
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: api,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType:'json',
     data: {},
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', makeBaseAuth('username', 'password'));
     }
});
```

Comment: jQuery is client side code.  Do you want to make the request from an HTML Script Tag, or server side code?

Comment: From server side code, and i have posted the answer, only waiting for tomorrow to accept it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can send HTTP requests using the [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) object. It has a `fetch(url, params)` method that returns a [`HTTPResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) with information about the result of the HTTP fetch.

```
function testapi(){

    var encode =  Utilities.base64Encode('username:password', Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
    Logger.log(encode);

    var option = {
      headers : {
            Authorization: "Basic "+ encode
      }   
    }

    var url = "URL";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option).getContentText()
    response = JSON.parse(response);

    for (var key in response){
      Logger.log(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `UrlFetchApp`. see the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but urlFetchApp uses OAuth Authentication not Basic Authentication.

Comment: no. you dont have to use oauth. you can pass any headers you want

Comment: in any case, why didnt you specify what you tried already and didnt work? that's why your score is negative

Comment: i believe the esencial parr is there (UrlFetchApp) which would be trivial to google if link breaks