# Write Google Forms Answer to Sheet as soon as it is entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form with some questions for which the user has to choose an answer from dropdown. The answers in the dropdown lists are fed from a Google Sheet.

Because I would like those dropdowns to be dynamic, I was wondering if there was any way in which I could instantly get the answer given by the user on a dropdown written to a Google Sheet. That way, I could change what came up in the next dropdown list.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378173/whats-the-server-side-equivalent-of-ajax-in-google-apps-scripts. It sounds like what you're asking for is an AJAX call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-script-for-forms)

Answer (score 0):

That it's not possible with Google Forms as there is no way to add a custom script to Google Forms respondent view.

Related

- [How to repeat a section in Google Forms before submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47022169/1595451)
- [Google Forms Onclick Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47673343/1595451)